# Errors in program for calculating integrals

Tags: python, math

I am trying to calculate the area of a graph using integrals.

The user is supposed to give me 3 numbers:

- x1, x2 – the bounds of the integral
- N is in how many pieces the program will divide the function

However, I keep getting wrong results.

The first difficulty that I faced is that range accepts only integers.

Also `z=(x2-x1)/N` if I try and make it a float, I can't make it a step after, and I don't make it float it approaches to zero so Python shows me an error that the step is zero.

Also how can I summarize `(z*(f(i)+f(i+z)/2)`?

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import math

def f(x) :
    y = (-1/6.0)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)
    return y 
x1=int(raw_input ('Δωστε το χ1 οπου αρχιζει η μετρηση του ολοκληρωματος \n ')) #greek letters
x2=int(raw_input ('Δωστε χ2 οπου θελετε να ολοκληρωνεται η μετρηση \n '))
N=int(raw_input('Δωστε τον αριθμο n που θα ειναι το πληθος \n των τραπεζιων που θα χρησιμοπιουνται στη προσσεγγιση  \n '))
z=(x2-x1)/N
for i in range(x1,x2,z):
    z=float(z)
    x1=float(x1)
    x2=float(x2)
    print (z*(f(i)+f(i+z))/2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let `x1`, `x2` and therefore the step size `z` be floats.
- Instead of a `for`-loop, a `while`-loop may be easier here.

---

```
x1 = float(raw_input ('Δωστε το χ1 οπου αρχιζει η μετρηση του ολοκληρωματος \n ')) #greek letters
x2 = float(raw_input ('Δωστε χ2 οπου θελετε να ολοκληρωνεται η μετρηση \n '))
N = int(raw_input('Δωστε τον αριθμο n που θα ειναι το πληθος \n των τραπεζιων που θα χρησιμοπιουνται στη προσσεγγιση  \n '))
z = (x2-x1)/N
x = x1
while x < x2:
    print (z*(f(x)+f(x+z))/2)
    x += z
```

Answer (score 6):

You are reading `x1`, you cast it to an `int` (read: throw away information), then you cast it back to a float upon each iteration. The lost information will not reappear.

```
z=(x2-x1)/N
```

Because your value are integers, it will perform an integer division, i.e. if N > (x2 - x1), `z` will be zero. And since you always want to choose a large `N`, `z` will always be zero.

Thus, `range()` cannot not work.

What you need to do instead is read the inputs as floats:

```
number = float(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
```

---

Note that applying `float()` repeatedly doesn't do anything useful. Thus, this code is not necessary:

```
for ...
    z=float(z)
    x1=float(x1)
    x2=float(x2)
```

---

> Also how can i summarise the (z*(f(i)+f(i+z)/2)?

You can't make it shorter, since `f()` isn't a linear function.

---

Another thing about `range()` is, that the step parameter must be an integer.

You can easily create your own range function though:

```
def frange(start, stop, steps):
    x = start
    difference = float(stop - start)
    for step in range(0, steps):
        next_x = start + difference * (1 + step) / steps
        yield x, next_x - x
        x = next_x
```

---

### Working code

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import math

def f(x) :
    y = (-1/6.0)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)
    return y 
x1 = float(raw_input ('Δωστε το χ1 οπου αρχιζει η μετρηση του ολοκληρωματος \n ')) #greek letters
x2 = float(raw_input ('Δωστε χ2 οπου θελετε να ολοκληρωνεται η μετρηση \n '))
N = int(raw_input('Δωστε τον αριθμο n που θα ειναι το πληθος \n των τραπεζιων που θα χρησιμοπιουνται στη προσσεγγιση  \n '))
result = 0
for x, delta_x in frange(x1, x2, N):
    result += delta_x * (f(x)+f(x+delta_x)) / 2
print result
```

Comment: Writing a float implementation of `range` isn't a good idea, since floating-point errors mean that it's unpredictable whether (an approximation to) the `stop` endpoint gets included or not.  For example, with your implementation, both `len(list(frange(0, 1, 1/7.)))` and `len(list(frange(0, 1, 1/8.)))` give `8` on my machine.  Better to keep the int-based range and compute the current `x` from that.

Comment: @MarkDickinson That's a good point, but I'm not sure whether it is that relevant, after all, using `1/7th` for the integration is too large a Δx anyway, and as Δx gets smaller, this possible off-by-one error should go away. Seeing that you are a mathematician, maybe you can give some less hand-wavy statement than me about the importance of that. But still, I'll implement that shortly.

Comment: I don't think the possibility for off-by-one error would go away:  in fact, the more steps you use, the larger the expected accumulated error from the additions (one per step).  Treating that error as roughly normally distributed (which may or may not be reasonable), I'd expect to get an extra unwanted point about half the time, for large number of steps.

Comment: Suggested replacement:  use `for i in range(N):`, then `x = x1 + i * delta_x` before the `sum += ...` line.

Comment: @MarkDickinson But wouldn't the error still accumulate in that way? See my edit for an updated version.

Comment: The point is to eliminate the possibility of using the wrong number of steps:  if you iterate over `range(N)` you'll obviously get `N` steps.  With the original `frange` code, you'd get either `N` or `N+1` steps depending on floating-point errors, and using an extra step would give a significantly wrong result.  (There are of course other sources of error here: truncation error from using a finite number of steps to approximate something continuous; numeric error from float approximation; but I'm not talking about those.)  Does this help any? :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes I understood what you meant with the possibility of doing an extra step. What I meant, however, is, that as `Δx` gets smaller, that additional area that you might add to the total area should be extremely small, and thus not give a "significantly wrong result". Of course this depends on the absolute value of the function for values near `x2`. I suppose my argument's downfall is, that you can't make the step size small enough to always compensate for that.

Comment: Sure, as `N` gets large the error from having an extra step gets smaller.  But why introduce the possibility for an extra step in the first place, when it's easy to avoid?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, you are right. In the changed code, as you've probably seen, I recalculate delta_x on every iteration, the idea being that it may make a difference due to accuracy issues since the actual difference between successive `x`s will vary, and also to encapsulate the calculation of delta_x.

Comment: Sorry for all the fussing, and thanks for the responses.  +1 from me. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson No problem but thanks rather for the insights.